# Php Login Personal Content

Tags: php

I have a problem with the login system. I want every user when Logged in into the application should have a unique content that is user1's content is different from that of user2, user3 etc. (eg Facebook). This is the code

```
$pass = $con->command("SELECT * FROM memlogin WHERE 
        email = '".$email."' AND
        password = '".$password."'

    ");

$res = $pass->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);



if (empty($res)) {


    $_SESSION['messge'] =  '<div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
            Login failed
          </div>';

    header("Location:../memlogin.php");

}else{

    $_SESSION['admin'] = $email;

    echo($res['memberid']);



    header("Location:../dazhboard.php");
```

and the code for the profile is

```
  <?php

  $output = $con->command("SELECT * FROM member");
  $row = $output->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);



  ?>


  <!-- Your Page Content Here -->

    <a href="memprof.php?id=<?php echo $row['id'] ?>">
              <button type="button">profile</button>
              </a>
```

Comment: and your question is... ?

Answer (score 0):

If i understand correctly, you have to make a modification in your database row where the user is (or make a new table assigned to the users row). Place a column into the user's row called content, and echo the user's content when he is logged in.

You can echo it then with `$row['content']`

Your question is a little bit vague though, but i think this is what you mean1